# React - functional components keep re-render when passing functions as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have an issue in my react app and i dont know how to solve it;

i have an array with values and chosen list
and a function to add item to the chosen list

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Parent from "./Parent";
export default function App() {
  const [chosenList, setChosenList] = useState([]);
  const array = ["dsadas", "dasdas", "dasdasd"];

  const addToChosenList = string => {
    setChosenList([...chosenList, string]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent
        arr={array}
        chosenList={chosenList}
        addToChosenList={addToChosenList}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Parent component that mapping through the array
and give the Nested component the props: item, addToChosenList, inList

```
import React from "react";
import Nested from "./Nested.js";

export default function Parent({ arr, addToChosenList, chosenList }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((item, index) => (
        <Nested
          key={index}
          item={item}
          addToChosenList={addToChosenList}
          inList={chosenList.findIndex(listitem => listitem === item) > -1}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Nested component that displays the item and giving it the addToChosenList function to add the item to the chosen list

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
export default memo(function Parent({ item, addToChosenList, inList }) {
  const childFunctionToAddToChosenList = () => {
    addToChosenList(item);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={childFunctionToAddToChosenList}>
      <div>{item}</div>
      {inList && <div>in List</div>}
    </div>
  );
});
```

every Nested component keeps re-render after i clicked only one item in the list
i believe it renders because of the function addToChosenList that changes when i change the state

anyone knows how to solve it ??

thanks :)

Comment: It is expected behaviour. When state of a Component is changed, all it's children (and sub-children) will be rerendered

Comment: But I’m using memo

Comment: Ok, didn't see the memo part. Perhaps you can try pass "setChosenList" into Nested and perform the "setChosenList([...chosenList, string]);" inside Nested ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`addToChosenList` will point to a new reference on every re-render, wrap it in [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) which will keep the same reference across re-renders unless one of the variables inside of the dependencies array has changed, if we pass an empty array the function will keep the same reference across the entire component lifecycle.

you will also need to use a functional update to avoid stale state due to the closure

```js
const addToChosenList = useCallback(string => {
  setChosenList(prevState => [...prevState, string]);
}, []);
```

Comment: what if this method has dependencies that makes it re-create ?