# Why my App keeps rerendering on any action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I noticed this strange behavior of my App, that when I do anything on it  (write something in the search field, create a new list, etc) my page gets rerendererd. Of course, I cannot find the source of it.

Below is the the look of my page, when it is loaded the first time, with default (blank) search results.

[image: Default Search Result]

And now, the result in profiler, when I type something in the searchBar (or create a new list, or anything):

[image: Page look after an action]

Here is my code of the App.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";
import NavBar from "../NavBar/NavBar";
import youtube from "../../apis/youtube";
import VideoList from "../VideoList/VideoList";
import VideoDetail from "../VideoDetail/VideoDetail";
import SideBar from "../SideBar/SideBar";

import "./App.css";

export const VideoContext = createContext();
export const FavoriteContext = createContext();

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

const App = () => {
    const [ videos, setVideos ] = useState([]);

    const [ searchedValue, setSearchedValue ] = useState({
        selectedVideo: null
    });

    const handleSelectedVideo = (singleRenderedVideo) => {
        setSearchedValue((previous) => ({
            ...previous,
            selectedVideo: singleRenderedVideo
        }));
    };

    const handleSearch = async (inputText) => {
        const response = await youtube.get("/search", {
            params: {
                q: inputText,
                part: "snippet",
                type: "video",
                maxResults: 16,
                key: API_KEY
            }
        });

        setVideos(response.data.items);
        setSearchedValue({
            selectedVideo: response.data.items[0] //take the first search result and make it appear as a playable one
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        handleSearch();
    }, []);

    //By the user newly created lists
    const [ lists, setLists ] = useState([]);

    const addList = (newList) => {
        setLists((prevLists) => {
            return [ ...prevLists, newList ];
        });
    };

    const onDeleteList = (id) => {
        setLists((prevLists) => {
            return prevLists.filter((listItem, index) => {
                return index !== id;
            });
        });
    };

    //Render(Play) Favorited Video
    const [ favoritedItem, setFavoritedItem ] = useState({
        clickedFavoritedVideo: null
    });

    const handleSelectedFavorite = (renderFavorite) => {
        setFavoritedItem((previous) => ({
            ...previous,
            clickedFavoritedVideo: renderFavorite
        }));
    };

    //Add a newly favorited video to a, by user created, list (BUG: for now the favorited video is added to EVERY, by the user, created list)
    const [ favoritedList, setFavoritedList ] = useState([]);

    const handleFavoritedVideo = (favoritedElement, selectedList) => {
        setFavoritedList((previousFavorited) => {
            return [ { favoritedElement, selectedList }, ...previousFavorited ];
        });
    };

    const deleteFavorited = (id) => {
        setFavoritedList((prevLists) => {
            return prevLists.filter((listItem, index) => {
                return index !== id;
            });
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <NavBar handleSearch={handleSearch} />
            <div className="content">
                <SideBar
                    addList={addList}
                    lists={lists}
                    handleSelectedFavorite={handleSelectedFavorite}
                    favoritedList={favoritedList}
                    onDeleteList={onDeleteList}
                    onDeleteFavorited={deleteFavorited}
                />

                <main className="video">
                    <VideoContext.Provider value={handleSelectedVideo}>
                        <FavoriteContext.Provider value={handleFavoritedVideo}>
                            <VideoDetail
                                selectedVideo={searchedValue.selectedVideo}
                                clickedFavoritedVideo={
                                    favoritedItem.clickedFavoritedVideo
                                }
                            />
                            <VideoList listOfVideos={videos} lists={lists} />
                        </FavoriteContext.Provider>
                    </VideoContext.Provider>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I will not post my whole app here, because it is a lot of files. I just give a link to my gitHub:
[GitHub LINK](https://github.com/DariuszLegizynski/React-Movie_App)

I was trying to find a solution, as stated here:

[Link to SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043919/react-functional-components-keep-re-render-when-passing-functions-as-props)

which is like my case, but it didn't help (maybe because I was not using `memo`):

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import NavBar from "../NavBar/NavBar";
import youtube from "../../apis/youtube";
import VideoList from "../VideoList/VideoList";
import VideoDetail from "../VideoDetail/VideoDetail";
import SideBar from "../SideBar/SideBar";

import "./App.css";

export const VideoContext = createContext();
export const FavoriteContext = createContext();

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

const App = () => {
    const [ videos, setVideos ] = useState([]);

    const [ searchedValue, setSearchedValue ] = useState({
        selectedVideo: null
    });

    const handleSelectedVideo = useCallback((singleRenderedVideo) => {
        setSearchedValue((previous) => ({
            ...previous,
            selectedVideo: singleRenderedVideo
        }));
    }, []);

    const handleSearch = async (inputText) => {
        const response = await youtube.get("/search", {
            params: {
                q: inputText,
                part: "snippet",
                type: "video",
                maxResults: 16,
                key: API_KEY
            }
        });

        setVideos(response.data.items);
        setSearchedValue({
            selectedVideo: response.data.items[0] //take the first search result and make it appear as a playable one
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        handleSearch();
    }, []);

    //By the user newly created lists
    const [ lists, setLists ] = useState([]);

    const addList = useCallback((newList) => {
        setLists((prevLists) => {
            return [ ...prevLists, newList ];
        });
    }, []);

    const onDeleteList = useCallback((id) => {
        setLists((prevLists) => {
            return prevLists.filter((listItem, index) => {
                return index !== id;
            });
        });
    }, []);

    //Render(Play) Favorited Video
    const [ favoritedItem, setFavoritedItem ] = useState({
        clickedFavoritedVideo: null
    });

    const handleSelectedFavorite = useCallback((renderFavorite) => {
        setFavoritedItem((previous) => ({
            ...previous,
            clickedFavoritedVideo: renderFavorite
        }));
    }, []);

    //Add a newly favorited video to a, by user created, list (BUG: for now the favorited video is added to EVERY, by the user, created list)
    const [ favoritedList, setFavoritedList ] = useState([]);

    const handleFavoritedVideo = useCallback((favoritedElement, selectedList) => {
        setFavoritedList((previousFavorited) => {
            return [ { favoritedElement, selectedList }, ...previousFavorited ];
        });
    }, []);

    const deleteFavorited = useCallback((id) => {
        setFavoritedList((prevLists) => {
            return prevLists.filter((listItem, index) => {
                return index !== id;
            });
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <NavBar handleSearch={handleSearch} />
            <div className="content">
                <SideBar
                    addList={addList}
                    lists={lists}
                    handleSelectedFavorite={handleSelectedFavorite}
                    favoritedList={favoritedList}
                    onDeleteList={onDeleteList}
                    onDeleteFavorited={deleteFavorited}
                />

                <main className="video">
                    <VideoContext.Provider value={handleSelectedVideo}>
                        <FavoriteContext.Provider value={handleFavoritedVideo}>
                            <VideoDetail
                                selectedVideo={searchedValue.selectedVideo}
                                clickedFavoritedVideo={
                                    favoritedItem.clickedFavoritedVideo
                                }
                            />
                            <VideoList listOfVideos={videos} lists={lists} />
                        </FavoriteContext.Provider>
                    </VideoContext.Provider>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I also tried to give a type for my buttons (`type="button"`), which currently have no type, like as in:

CreateNewList.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import iconSprites from "../../images/sprite.svg";
import shortid from "shortid";

const CreateNewList = ({ onAdd }) => {
    const [ list, setList ] = useState({
        id: shortid.generate(),
        title: ""
    });

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { value } = event.target;

        setList((prevList) => {
            return {
                ...prevList,
                title: value
            };
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    const submitNewList = (event) => {
        onAdd({ ...list });
        setList({ id: shortid.generate(), title: "" });
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <li className="new-list__item">
                <form>
                    <div className="new-list__link">
                        <button
                            onClick={submitNewList}
                            className="new-list__btn-plus btn"
                        >
                            <svg className="new-list__icon">
                                <use href={iconSprites + "#icon-circle-with-plus"} />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <input
                            className="new-list__input"
                            name="title"
                            value={list.title}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            placeholder="New List"
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default CreateNewList;
```

but it also didn't help. Maybe because they are not in `<form>`?

So that is it. Maybe someone can help me with my issue?

To have all of the questions in one place:

1. Why my app keeps rerendering?
2. Should I use `memo` with `useCallback`?
3. Should I put my `button`s in a `<form>` and give them a type?

Comment: You have setState on your App component. Whenever your type in your search bar it updates your App component which is basically your whole App. What do you expect?

Comment: Well, that it would not update? So does it mean, that I must reorganize my whole project and put the setState in the components, that actually are using it? And then get access to it via a callback?